# Analytic functions $f(z)$ whose real parts only depend on $|z|$

Tags: complex-analysis

I 'm trying to find the general form of the analytic functions $f(z)$ whose real parts only depend on $|z|$.Can anyone give me some hint.

Comment: Look at harmonic functions (and their conjugates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(z) = f(e^{z})$ which is analytic. Then $Re(g(z)))$ depends only on $Re(z)$, so that $g'(z) = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{g(z+ih)-g(z)}{ih} = \lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{i\,Im(g(z+ih))-i\,Im(g(z))}{ih}$ is purely real,

implying that $g''(z) = 0$, since $g''(z)=\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{g'(z+h)-g'(z)}{h} $ is real too, and $g'(z+i h) = g'(z) +i h g''(z)+ o(|h|))$ that is not real if $g''(z) \ne 0$.

Hence $g'(z) = a$ is constant (and real) and $g(z)  = az+b$ is linear.

Finally $f(z) = a\log(z)+b$, $\ \ a \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I think there are some primes missing when you write $g''$ as a limit.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, we are trying to find a harmonic function of the form $g(|z|)$. Observe
\begin{align}
\partial_x[g(|z|)] = g'(|z|) \frac{x}{|z|}\ \ \text{ and } \ \ \partial_{xx}[g(|z|)] = g''(|z|) \frac{x^2}{|z|^2}+g'(|z|) \frac{y^2}{|z|^3}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\Delta[g(|z|)] =  g''(|z|)+\frac{g'(|z|)}{|z|}=0.
\end{align}
Thus, it suffices to solve the ode
\begin{align}
g''(r) + \frac{g'(r)}{r} = 0 \ \ \Rightarrow&\ \ \ \frac{d}{dr}\log|g'(r)|= -\frac{1}{r}\\
\Rightarrow&\ \ \ g(r) = A\log r+B.
\end{align}
Hence the only harmonic function that depends only on $|z|$ is $A\log|z|+B$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\text{Re}(f(e^z))$ depends only on $\text{Re}(z)$.  Use the Schwarz reflection principle.